# Date of formatting of drive encrypted with Disk Utility

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I had a computer and a backup drive. Computer A held the data and had a backup in drive B. Drive B is encrypted with Disk Utility on macOS and the password is stored and has a hint in computer A. Computer A got stolen.

Following on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266468/how-to-recover-a-password-hint-from-a-drive-encrypted-with-disk-utility) and [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299558/how-do-i-get-the-password-hint-for-an-encrypted-disk), I was unable to recover the password hint.

If I could know the date that drive B was formatted and encrypted, I would already have a lead for the password. Is that possible?

Here is the ouptut of `diskutil coreStorage list`:

```
$diskutil coreStorage list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group B2800A76-F42F-40FF-84BB-2511E928BF29
    =========================================================
    Name:         Time Machine Encryped
    Status:       Online
    Size:         239712407552 B (239.7 GB)
    Free Space:   16318464 B (16.3 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 554CBE3D-5212-4FF8-A7A6-A95FCAA7B511
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     239712407552 B (239.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 422F58D5-FF65-472A-8942-1F4E4F3CA83A
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Locked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 2930C7CC-4EE4-43AB-B1FB-81756A1CC0E5
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  -none-
            Status:                Locked
            Size (Total):          239343763456 B (239.3 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Time Machine Encryped
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

Comment: The first one! The password hint or the date of encryption would help me a lot, but be almost irrelevant for an attacker.

Comment: The date the filesystem was created isn't typically something that would be stored... Though "_could_" be derived from file times / metadata (which is encrypted)... I can't comment with authority on Apple filesystems.

Comment: It's one computer and one backup drive. Computer A held the data and had a backup in drive B. Drive B is encrypted and the password is stored and has a hint in computer A. Computer A got stolen. I'll add this in the question.